# $\sqrt{n}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{S_{n}}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right]\overset{d}{\rightarrow}\ ?$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n,\ldots$ are iid r.v.s. with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

If we want to prove that:

$$\sqrt{n}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{S_{n}}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

converges in distribution.

Can you do it in the following way?

$$\sqrt{n}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{S_{n}}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right]= \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{S_{n}}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right]= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left[n\Phi\left(\frac{S_{n}}{n}\right)-\frac{n}{2}\right]= \left \{ \frac{S_{n}}{n}\overset{p}{\rightarrow} \mu=0 \right \}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left[n\Phi(0)-\frac{n}{2}\right]= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left[\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\right]= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot 0\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0 \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot 0\overset{d}{\rightarrow}0$$

When $n\overset{}{\rightarrow}\infty$

Where I have used WLLN and Cramer-Slutsky.

Comment: Trying to erase your footprints?

Comment: Gee! My answer was unaccepted! What a retaliation... $\langle$ *Faints* $\rangle$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\Phi''$ is bounded by $1$, Taylor-Lagrange formula reads
$$
\Phi\left(\frac{S_n}n\right)=\Phi(0)+\Phi'(0)\frac{S_n}n+R_n\frac{S_n^2}{n^2},
$$
where $|R_n|\leqslant1$ almost surely. Let $Z_n=\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$. Since $\Phi(0)=\frac12$ and $\Phi'(0)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, the random variable of interest is
$$
T_n=\sqrt{n}\left(\Phi\left(\frac{S_n}n\right)-\frac12\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}Z_n+\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}}Z_n^2.
$$
Since $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable, the last term converges in distribution to $0$ and $T_n$ converges in distribution to a centered normal random variable with variance $\frac1{2\pi}$.

Comment: To answer a question in your post, no, one cannot replace $\Phi\left(\frac{S_n}n\right)$ by $\Phi(0)$ like that.